# SQL Server 2008 R2: About 15 000 000 eventlog-rows (How to query a list of all the different errors?)

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I have a database which is very big and stores a lot of eventlogs, around 15 million rows.
When I try this query, it is totally impossible to get some results.

Any idea how I could do this? Maybe indexed views?

(BTW.: the question is just about the performance problem. Apart from that the query is working if there are much less entries.)

```
SELECT dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
FROM dbo.EntryTypes
INNER JOIN dbo.Main ON dbo.EntryTypes.pk_EntryType = dbo.Main.fk_EntryType
INNER JOIN dbo.EventIds ON dbo.EventIds.pk_EventId = dbo.Main.fk_EventId
INNER JOIN dbo.LogNames ON dbo.LogNames.pk_LogName = dbo.Main.fk_LogName
INNER JOIN dbo.Servers ON dbo.Servers.pk_Server = dbo.Main.fk_Server
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources ON dbo.Sources.pk_Source = dbo.Main.fk_Source
WHERE dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType = 'Error'
GROUP BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
ORDER BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
```

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntryTypes]
(
    [pk_EntryType] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntryType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_EntryTypes] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_EntryType] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogNames]
(
    [pk_LogName] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LogNames] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_LogName] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sources]
(
    [pk_Source] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sources] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_Source] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Servers]
(
    [pk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Server] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Servers] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_Server] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Main]
(
    [pk_Main] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EventId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Msg] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [Indx] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Source] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_LogName] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_EntryType] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Main] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_Main] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Errors]
(
    [pk_Error] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorMsg] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorMsgFull] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Errors] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_Error] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Errors] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Errors_Servers] 
  FOREIGN KEY([fk_Server]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Servers] ([pk_Server])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Errors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Errors_Servers]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_EntryTypes] 
   FOREIGN KEY([fk_EntryType]) REFERENCES [dbo].[EntryTypes] ([pk_EntryType])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_EntryTypes]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_LogNames] 
   FOREIGN KEY([fk_LogName]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LogNames] ([pk_LogName])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_LogNames]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Servers] 
   FOREIGN KEY([fk_Server]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Servers] ([pk_Server])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Servers]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Sources] 
   FOREIGN KEY([fk_Source]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Sources] ([pk_Source])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Sources]
```

Comment: Why do you need the `group by`?

Comment: Otherwise I get doubles. There are a lot of events which are the same.

Comment: From what I can tell, you have a table with about 15,000,000 rows.  You are doing a join on the table to a bunch of reference tables, and then aggregating by the main id on the table.  Even if the query did return results, it might take a little while to read 15,000,000 rows.  Perhaps you should ask another question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Actually the question is just about the performance problem. Apart from that the query is working if there are much less entries.
I never worked before with such "big" DBs... Because of that I'm asking here what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
Now I get the results in a, for me, acceptable time (+- 100 Seconds for about 1 500 000 lines).
I added a non-unique, non-clustered index for every FK and also a composite index with the fields which I use in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15 million rows isn't all that big. Just make sure you have good indexes and adequate RAM in the server. In this case, adding an index on the `Main.fk_EntryType` will likely greatly improve your performance. Including `fk_Server`, `fk_LogName`, and `fk_Source` in the same index, in that same order (to match the query's GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses), might help as well.

If those additional tables all really do have just the one column, you can probably do better still by just storing that data in the Main table in the first place. This would allow the index to cover the data for the query in the correct order, saving the database a lot of work re-ordering the results. If that's not possible, an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) may be required.

One final option is to move the `Main.Msg` ntext column to it's own table. If your database server is very memory constrained, this can allow the database to keep the rest of the `Main` table in memory for faster retrieval, without needing to add an additional index.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
Now I get the results in a, for me, acceptable time (+- 100 Seconds for about 1 500 000 lines).
I added a non-unique, non-clustered index for every FK and also a composite index with the fields which I use in my query.

Comment: @Dobi One index per key won't really help that query, and it has a cost in terms of slower inserts. You only need the single index that includes all the keys, and make sure it uses the proper order to match your WHERE clause and then GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all;

If you have many rows in dbo.[EntryTypes], ensure you have an index on [EntryType] (if the 'Error' rows are fewer then a couple % of the content of the table and if you have enough ). Make it a filtered index to eek out even more performance.

Try to put NONCLUSTERED indexes on all columns used in joins (if multiple column indexes, always use the column containing the most nr of Unique values)

Try to have all the columns in the query in indexes to get the effect of a covering index.

Try to remove your GROUP BY and use DISTINCT.

Also, check your query plan to see which operations take the most time and what, i any, new indices are recommended...

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
Now I get the results in a, for me, acceptable time (+- 100 Seconds for about 1 500 000 lines).
I added a non-unique, non-clustered index for every FK and also a composite index with the fields which I use in my query.

Comment: Dobi: Good! :) Remember to check the network speed if you want to work on optimising further... 1.5M records can take time to pull over the network.
<p>(Ex: Avg Record size being returns = 500 bytes. * 1.5M = 750Mbyte. 750Mbyte in ~100 s means ~7.5Mbyte/s which might be bottlenecking your query/results</p>

Comment: Yes, thx! ;) That is no problem in this case. No one accesses this data from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
With 5 joins I bet it looped on every join and did the where last
You could also just do a select distinct without the group by but it would probably be the same query plan

And put a non-clustered index on dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType

If that does not fix it then add a non-clusted index on dbo.Main.Msg
And I don't agree with Joel that putting Main.Msg in a separate table would help
Nor that adding all those FK to the dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType Index would help

```
SELECT  dbo.Main.Msg
      , dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
      , dbo.EventIds.EventId
      , dbo.LogNames.LogName
      , dbo.Servers.Server
      , dbo.Sources.Source         
  FROM dbo.Main
  JOIN dbo.EntryTypes
    ON dbo.EntryTypes.pk_EntryType = dbo.Main.fk_EntryType 
   AND dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType = 'Error'
  JOIN dbo.EventIds 
    ON dbo.EventIds.pk_EventId     = dbo.Main.fk_EventId   
  JOIN dbo.LogNames 
    ON dbo.LogNames.pk_LogName     = dbo.Main.fk_LogName   
  JOIN dbo.Servers
    ON dbo.Servers.pk_Server       = dbo.Main.fk_Server    
  JOIN dbo.Sources 
    ON dbo.Sources.pk_Source       = dbo.Main.fk_Source    
 GROUP BY  
       dbo.Main.Msg
     , dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
     , dbo.EventIds.EventId
     , dbo.LogNames.LogName
     , dbo.Servers.Server
     , dbo.Sources.Source
 ORDER BY ...
```

Why don't you have unique contraints on all those `[nvarchar](50)`?

And this is just odd.  With this design a could have the duplicate msg creating unique rows but you are not reporting [pk_Main].

Comment: I wasn't suggesting adding anything to the EntryType table. I did recommend adding columns to an index on Main that leads with the fk_EntryType column. For moving Msg... that will only help if the OP is working off of a severely memory-constrained server, as it may allow keeping everything else in the original table in memory. So you're right: it's a fairly limited scenario in which that could help, but since he considers 15M rows to be "big", I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn OK so we don't agree.  I don't agree that group by  dbo.Main.Msg will benefit from another table - I think it will hurt it.